# Get letters instead of numbers in option button with Access

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I was trying to design a form in access, when i was in the marital status field i think it was a good idea to use a group of option buttons but i can save letters only numbers. This is not bad but i would like to save letters because is easier to remember. I have 4 values. I have other similar fields, like sex, education and so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [ask]

Comment: Since you should only have one option button set to true for an individual (and I assume your labels for the options are things like Married / Divorced / Single...), you could use VBA to translate the number to a letter. i.e. in the Form_Current event, you could use something like 'If Me.MaritalStatus = "S" then Me.OptSingle = True' Is this similar to what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can use *Choose*. It returns *values* from input of 1 to n and *Null* for values outside the range. This can be used by *Nz* to return a value for unknown inputs.

This can be used a *ControlSource* for a textbox, here for values between 1 and 4:

```
=Nz(Choose([NameOfYourOptionBox], "Male", "Female", "Hermaphrodite", "None"), "Unknown")
```